# Работа в docker (php8.0+mysql8.0+nginx+phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, docker

нашел конфиг по развертке среды в docker [php+mysql+nginx](https://tretyakov.net/post/lokalnaya-sreda-dlya-php-razrabotki-s-pomoshhyu-docker/).
Я только начинаю разбираться с docker. В статье описывается mysql 5.7 и php 7.3 и версия третья docker-compose. Я бы хотел использоваться версию doker-compose 3.9, версию php 8.0 и версию mysql 8.0. Но при замене соответствующих значений в docker-compose.yml и в Dockerfile при сборке вылезают ошибки. В чем может быть проблема? Исходные конфиги прикрепил.
Я пытался просто изменить версии на более новые, не сработало. А со стандартными версиями этого конфига все билдится.

docker-compose.yml

```
    # Файл docker-compose должен начинаться с указания версии.
version: '3'

# Сети
networks:
    internal:

# Ниже список наших сервисов (контейнеров). NGINX, PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin
services:
    nginx:
        # Какую версию образа nginx из официального хранилища DockerHub используем
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        # Ниже прокидываем порты. NGINX в контейнере работает на дефолтном 80, а мы возьмем 8000
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        # Монтируем директории, слева директории на основной системе, справа - куда они монтируются в контейнере
        volumes:
          - ./sites:/var/www
          - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
          - ./data/logs:/var/log/nginx/
        # Зависимости  
        depends_on:
          - php
          - mysql
        networks:
          - internal
    php:
        build:
          context: ./config/php
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        volumes:
          - ./sites:/var/www
          - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
        networks:
          - internal
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: mysql
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
          - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        # Задаем пароль для root пользователя
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        networks:
         - internal
```

Dockerfile

```
    # Для начала указываем исходный образ, он будет использован как основа
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# RUN выполняет идущую за ней команду в контексте нашего образа.
# В данном случае мы установим некоторые зависимости и модули PHP.
# Для установки модулей используем команду docker-php-ext-install.
# На каждый RUN создается новый слой в образе, поэтому рекомендуется объединять команды.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

    
# Ставим Composer'а.
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

USER www-data:www-data

# Указываем рабочую директорию для PHP
WORKDIR /var/www

# Запускаем контейнер
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Текст билдинга, если выставляю восьмые версии.

```
#6 9.065 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 less amd64 487-0.1+b1 [129 kB]
#6 9.141 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2 [782 kB]
#6 9.282 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libpcre2-8-0 amd64 10.32-5 [213 kB]
#6 9.303 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 wget amd64 1.20.1-1.1 [902 kB]
#6 9.448 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.64.0-4+deb10u2 [330 kB]
#6 9.563 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.2.6-2+deb10u1 [106 kB]
#6 9.632 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 liberror-perl all 0.17027-2 [30.9 kB]
#6 9.645 Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3 [1620 kB]
#6 10.83 Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3 [5633 kB]
#6 13.46 Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libpng16-16 amd64 1.6.36-6 [292 kB]
#6 13.52 Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libfreetype6 amd64 2.9.1-3+deb10u2 [380 kB]
#6 13.58 Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 zlib1g-dev amd64 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1 [214 kB]
#6 13.61 Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libpng-dev amd64 1.6.36-6 [300 kB]
#6 13.66 Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libfreetype6-dev amd64 2.9.1-3+deb10u2 [544 kB]
#6 13.73 Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libjpeg62-turbo amd64 1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1 [133 kB]
#6 13.74 Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libjpeg62-turbo-dev amd64 1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1 [208 kB]
#6 13.78 Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmcrypt4 amd64 2.5.8-3.4 [72.9 kB]
#6 13.79 Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libmcrypt-dev amd64 2.5.8-3.4 [94.3 kB]
#6 13.80 Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libpng-tools amd64 1.6.36-6 [140 kB]
#6 13.82 Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxau6 amd64 1:1.0.8-1+b2 [19.9 kB]
#6 13.82 Get:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxdmcp6 amd64 1:1.1.2-3 [26.3 kB]
#6 13.83 Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxcb1 amd64 1.13.1-2 [137 kB]
#6 13.84 Get:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libx11-data all 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u2 [299 kB]
#6 13.88 Get:24 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libx11-6 amd64 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u2 [757 kB]
#6 13.97 Get:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxext6 amd64 2:1.3.3-1+b2 [52.5 kB]
#6 13.98 Get:26 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxmuu1 amd64 2:1.1.2-2+b3 [23.9 kB]
#6 13.99 Get:27 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libzip4 amd64 1.5.1-4 [50.7 kB]
#6 13.99 Get:28 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libzip-dev amd64 1.5.1-4 [158 kB]
#6 14.01 Get:29 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 xauth amd64 1:1.0.10-1 [40.3 kB]
#6 14.15 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#6 14.18 Fetched 13.7 MB in 5s (2703 kB/s)
#6 14.20 Selecting previously unselected package less.
(Reading database ... 12690 files and directories currently installed.)
#6 14.22 Preparing to unpack .../00-less_487-0.1+b1_amd64.deb ...
#6 14.23 Unpacking less (487-0.1+b1) ...
#6 14.27 Selecting previously unselected package openssh-client.
#6 14.28 Preparing to unpack .../01-openssh-client_1%3a7.9p1-10+deb10u2_amd64.deb ...
#6 14.28 Unpacking openssh-client (1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2) ...
#6 14.37 Selecting previously unselected package libpcre2-8-0:amd64.
#6 14.37 Preparing to unpack .../02-libpcre2-8-0_10.32-5_amd64.deb ...
#6 14.38 Unpacking libpcre2-8-0:amd64 (10.32-5) ...
#6 14.43 Selecting previously unselected package wget.
#6 14.43 Preparing to unpack .../03-wget_1.20.1-1.1_amd64.deb ...
#6 14.43 Unpacking wget (1.20.1-1.1) ...
#6 14.54 Selecting previously unselected package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.
#6 14.55 Preparing to unpack .../04-libcurl3-gnutls_7.64.0-4+deb10u2_amd64.deb ...
#6 14.56 Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.64.0-4+deb10u2) ...
#6 14.65 Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
#6 14.65 Preparing to unpack .../05-libexpat1_2.2.6-2+deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
#6 14.65 Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.6-2+deb10u1) ...
#6 14.69 Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
#6 14.70 Preparing to unpack .../06-liberror-perl_0.17027-2_all.deb ...
#6 14.70 Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17027-2) ...
#6 14.73 Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
#6 14.73 Preparing to unpack .../07-git-man_1%3a2.20.1-2+deb10u3_all.deb ...
#6 14.73 Unpacking git-man (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3) ...
#6 14.85 Selecting previously unselected package git.
#6 14.85 Preparing to unpack .../08-git_1%3a2.20.1-2+deb10u3_amd64.deb ...
#6 14.86 Unpacking git (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3) ...
#6 15.39 Selecting previously unselected package libpng16-16:amd64.
#6 15.40 Preparing to unpack .../09-libpng16-16_1.6.36-6_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.40 Unpacking libpng16-16:amd64 (1.6.36-6) ...
#6 15.45 Selecting previously unselected package libfreetype6:amd64.
#6 15.45 Preparing to unpack .../10-libfreetype6_2.9.1-3+deb10u2_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.45 Unpacking libfreetype6:amd64 (2.9.1-3+deb10u2) ...
#6 15.51 Selecting previously unselected package zlib1g-dev:amd64.
#6 15.51 Preparing to unpack .../11-zlib1g-dev_1%3a1.2.11.dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.51 Unpacking zlib1g-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-1) ...
#6 15.55 Selecting previously unselected package libpng-dev:amd64.
#6 15.55 Preparing to unpack .../12-libpng-dev_1.6.36-6_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.55 Unpacking libpng-dev:amd64 (1.6.36-6) ...
#6 15.61 Selecting previously unselected package libfreetype6-dev:amd64.
#6 15.61 Preparing to unpack .../13-libfreetype6-dev_2.9.1-3+deb10u2_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.62 Unpacking libfreetype6-dev:amd64 (2.9.1-3+deb10u2) ...
#6 15.70 Selecting previously unselected package libjpeg62-turbo:amd64.
#6 15.70 Preparing to unpack .../14-libjpeg62-turbo_1%3a1.5.2-2+deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.70 Unpacking libjpeg62-turbo:amd64 (1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1) ...
#6 15.76 Selecting previously unselected package libjpeg62-turbo-dev:amd64.
#6 15.76 Preparing to unpack .../15-libjpeg62-turbo-dev_1%3a1.5.2-2+deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.76 Unpacking libjpeg62-turbo-dev:amd64 (1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1) ...
#6 15.81 Selecting previously unselected package libmcrypt4.
#6 15.81 Preparing to unpack .../16-libmcrypt4_2.5.8-3.4_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.81 Unpacking libmcrypt4 (2.5.8-3.4) ...
#6 15.84 Selecting previously unselected package libmcrypt-dev.
#6 15.84 Preparing to unpack .../17-libmcrypt-dev_2.5.8-3.4_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.84 Unpacking libmcrypt-dev (2.5.8-3.4) ...
#6 15.88 Selecting previously unselected package libpng-tools.
#6 15.88 Preparing to unpack .../18-libpng-tools_1.6.36-6_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.88 Unpacking libpng-tools (1.6.36-6) ...
#6 15.92 Selecting previously unselected package libxau6:amd64.
#6 15.92 Preparing to unpack .../19-libxau6_1%3a1.0.8-1+b2_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.92 Unpacking libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.8-1+b2) ...
#6 15.95 Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp6:amd64.
#6 15.95 Preparing to unpack .../20-libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.2-3_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.95 Unpacking libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.2-3) ...
#6 15.98 Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1:amd64.
#6 15.98 Preparing to unpack .../21-libxcb1_1.13.1-2_amd64.deb ...
#6 15.99 Unpacking libxcb1:amd64 (1.13.1-2) ...
#6 16.02 Selecting previously unselected package libx11-data.
#6 16.02 Preparing to unpack .../22-libx11-data_2%3a1.6.7-1+deb10u2_all.deb ...
#6 16.02 Unpacking libx11-data (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.11 Selecting previously unselected package libx11-6:amd64.
#6 16.11 Preparing to unpack .../23-libx11-6_2%3a1.6.7-1+deb10u2_amd64.deb ...
#6 16.11 Unpacking libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.20 Selecting previously unselected package libxext6:amd64.
#6 16.20 Preparing to unpack .../24-libxext6_2%3a1.3.3-1+b2_amd64.deb ...
#6 16.20 Unpacking libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.3-1+b2) ...
#6 16.24 Selecting previously unselected package libxmuu1:amd64.
#6 16.24 Preparing to unpack .../25-libxmuu1_2%3a1.1.2-2+b3_amd64.deb ...
#6 16.24 Unpacking libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.2-2+b3) ...
#6 16.27 Selecting previously unselected package libzip4:amd64.
#6 16.27 Preparing to unpack .../26-libzip4_1.5.1-4_amd64.deb ...
#6 16.28 Unpacking libzip4:amd64 (1.5.1-4) ...
#6 16.30 Selecting previously unselected package libzip-dev:amd64.
#6 16.30 Preparing to unpack .../27-libzip-dev_1.5.1-4_amd64.deb ...
#6 16.31 Unpacking libzip-dev:amd64 (1.5.1-4) ...
#6 16.35 Selecting previously unselected package xauth.
#6 16.35 Preparing to unpack .../28-xauth_1%3a1.0.10-1_amd64.deb ...
#6 16.36 Unpacking xauth (1:1.0.10-1) ...
#6 16.42 Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.2.6-2+deb10u1) ...
#6 16.43 Setting up libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.8-1+b2) ...
#6 16.43 Setting up libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.2-3) ...
#6 16.44 Setting up libxcb1:amd64 (1.13.1-2) ...
#6 16.45 Setting up openssh-client (1:7.9p1-10+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.53 Setting up libzip4:amd64 (1.5.1-4) ...
#6 16.54 Setting up less (487-0.1+b1) ...
#6 16.62 debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
#6 16.62 debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
#6 16.62 debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
#6 16.65 Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.64.0-4+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.69 Setting up liberror-perl (0.17027-2) ...
#6 16.70 Setting up libjpeg62-turbo:amd64 (1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1) ...
#6 16.70 Setting up libx11-data (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.71 Setting up libjpeg62-turbo-dev:amd64 (1:1.5.2-2+deb10u1) ...
#6 16.72 Setting up libpng16-16:amd64 (1.6.36-6) ...
#6 16.73 Setting up libpcre2-8-0:amd64 (10.32-5) ...
#6 16.74 Setting up zlib1g-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-1) ...
#6 16.75 Setting up git-man (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3) ...
#6 16.76 Setting up libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.76 Setting up libmcrypt4 (2.5.8-3.4) ...
#6 16.77 Setting up libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.2-2+b3) ...
#6 16.79 Setting up libzip-dev:amd64 (1.5.1-4) ...
#6 16.80 Setting up wget (1.20.1-1.1) ...
#6 16.81 Setting up libpng-tools (1.6.36-6) ...
#6 16.82 Setting up libpng-dev:amd64 (1.6.36-6) ...
#6 16.82 Setting up libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.3-1+b2) ...
#6 16.83 Setting up libmcrypt-dev (2.5.8-3.4) ...
#6 16.84 Setting up libfreetype6:amd64 (2.9.1-3+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.85 Setting up git (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3) ...
#6 16.88 Setting up xauth (1:1.0.10-1) ...
#6 16.89 Setting up libfreetype6-dev:amd64 (2.9.1-3+deb10u2) ...
#6 16.90 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
#6 18.66 Configuring for:
#6 18.66 PHP Api Version:         20200930
#6 18.66 Zend Module Api No:      20200930
#6 18.66 Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
#6 19.34 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#6 19.35 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#6 19.35 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#6 19.37 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#6 19.37 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
#6 19.38 checking for cc... cc
#6 19.40 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#6 19.46 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#6 19.46 checking for suffix of executables...
#6 19.50 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#6 19.56 checking for suffix of object files... o
#6 19.57 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#6 19.59 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#6 19.61 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#6 19.66 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#6 19.70 checking for icc... no
#6 19.71 checking for suncc... no
#6 19.71 checking for system library directory... lib
#6 19.71 checking if compiler supports -R... no
#6 19.72 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#6 19.76 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#6 19.77 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#6 19.77 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#6 19.80 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
#6 19.80 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
#6 19.80 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
#6 19.80 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#6 19.80 checking if debug is enabled... no
#6 19.82 checking if zts is enabled... no
#6 19.83 checking for gawk... no
#6 19.83 checking for nawk... nawk
#6 19.83 checking if nawk is broken... no
#6 19.83 checking for iconv support... yes, shared
#6 19.83 checking for iconv... yes
#6 19.87 checking if iconv is glibc's... yes
#6 19.90 checking if iconv supports errno... yes
#6 19.93 checking if iconv supports //IGNORE... no
#6 19.98 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#6 19.98 checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
#6 19.99 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
#6 19.99 checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
#6 19.99 checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
#6 19.99 checking whether ln -s works... yes
#6 19.99 checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
#6 20.01 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
#6 20.10 checking for sys/types.h... yes
#6 20.12 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
#6 20.15 checking for stdlib.h... yes
#6 20.17 checking for string.h... yes
#6 20.20 checking for memory.h... yes
#6 20.23 checking for strings.h... yes
#6 20.25 checking for inttypes.h... yes
#6 20.28 checking for stdint.h... yes
#6 20.31 checking for unistd.h... yes
#6 20.34 checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
#6 20.36 checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
#6 20.37 checking for dlfcn.h... yes
#6 20.37 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
#6 20.37 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
#6 20.43 checking for objdir... .libs
#6 20.43 checking for ar... ar
#6 20.43 checking for ranlib... ranlib
#6 20.44 checking for strip... strip
#6 20.48 checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
#6 20.50 checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
#6 20.50 checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
#6 20.52 checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
#6 20.58 checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
#6 20.61 checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
#6 20.62 checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
#6 20.65 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
#6 20.66 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
#6 20.66 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
#6 20.67 checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
#6 20.67 checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
#6 20.67 checking whether to build static libraries... no
#6 20.85
#6 20.85 creating libtool
#6 20.87 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
#6 20.93 configure: patching config.h.in
#6 20.94 configure: creating ./config.status
#6 20.98 config.status: creating config.h
#6 21.02 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -c /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c -o iconv.lo
#6 21.10 mkdir .libs
#6 21.10  cc -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -c /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/iconv.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/iconv.o
#6 21.67 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/libtool --mode=link cc -shared -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/iconv -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wl,-O1 -pie  -o iconv.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/modules  iconv.lo
#6 21.75 cc -shared  .libs/iconv.o   -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-soname -Wl,iconv.so -o .libs/iconv.so
#6 21.77 creating iconv.la
#6 21.78 (cd .libs && rm -f iconv.la && ln -s ../iconv.la iconv.la)
#6 21.78 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/libtool --mode=install cp ./iconv.la /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/modules
#6 21.81 cp ./.libs/iconv.so /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/modules/iconv.so
#6 21.82 cp ./.libs/iconv.lai /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/modules/iconv.la
#6 21.84 PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/modules
#6 21.85 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#6 21.85 Libraries have been installed in:
#6 21.85    /usr/src/php/ext/iconv/modules
#6 21.85
#6 21.85 If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
#6 21.85 in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
#6 21.85 specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
#6 21.85 flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
#6 21.85    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
#6 21.85      during execution
#6 21.85    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
#6 21.85      during linking
#6 21.85    - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
#6 21.85    - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
#6 21.85
#6 21.85 See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
#6 21.85 more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
#6 21.85 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#6 21.85
#6 21.85 Build complete.
#6 21.85 Don't forget to run 'make test'.
#6 21.85
#6 21.87 Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/
#6 21.90 Installing header files:          /usr/local/include/php/
#6 22.03
#6 22.03 warning: iconv (iconv.so) is already loaded!
#6 22.03
#6 22.03 find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
#6 22.03 find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
#6 22.04 find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
#6 22.04 find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
#6 22.04 find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
#6 22.05 rm -f libphp.la      modules/* libs/*
#6 22.05 rm -f ext/opcache/jit/zend_jit_x86.c
#6 22.07 Configuring for:
#6 22.07 PHP Api Version:         20200930
#6 22.07 Zend Module Api No:      20200930
#6 22.07 Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
#6 22.70 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#6 22.71 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#6 22.71 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#6 22.73 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#6 22.73 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
#6 22.73 checking for cc... cc
#6 22.75 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#6 22.78 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#6 22.79 checking for suffix of executables...
#6 22.82 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#6 22.88 checking for suffix of object files... o
#6 22.90 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#6 22.91 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#6 22.93 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#6 22.96 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#6 22.99 checking for icc... no
#6 23.00 checking for suncc... no
#6 23.01 checking for system library directory... lib
#6 23.01 checking if compiler supports -R... no
#6 23.02 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#6 23.06 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#6 23.06 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#6 23.06 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#6 23.10 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
#6 23.10 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
#6 23.10 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
#6 23.10 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#6 23.10 checking if debug is enabled... no
#6 23.11 checking if zts is enabled... no
#6 23.12 checking for gawk... no
#6 23.12 checking for nawk... nawk
#6 23.12 checking if nawk is broken... no
#6 23.12 checking whether to enable multibyte string support... yes, shared
#6 23.12 checking whether to enable multibyte regex support (requires oniguruma)... yes
#6 23.13 checking for oniguruma... no
#6 23.13 configure: error: Package requirements (oniguruma) were not met:
#6 23.13
#6 23.13 No package 'oniguruma' found
#6 23.13
#6 23.13 Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
#6 23.13 installed software in a non-standard prefix.
#6 23.13
#6 23.13 Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ONIG_CFLAGS
#6 23.13 and ONIG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
#6 23.13 See the pkg-config man page for more details.
#6 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y         curl         wget         git         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmcrypt-dev         libpng-dev          libzip-dev     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd]: exit code: 1
------
 > [2/4] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y         curl         wget         git         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmcrypt-dev         libpng-dev           libzip-dev     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y         curl         wget         git         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libmcrypt-dev         libpng-dev            libzip-dev     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd]: exit code: 1
Service 'php' failed to build : Build failed
```

**

Comment: про самое главное забыли: ошибки-то приведите, пожалуйста (нажав [edit]).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin добавил всю простыню текста билдинга, т.к. не знаю, что именно нужно. Только без начала, т.к. весь текст не влез

Comment: `No package 'oniguruma' found` → yandex/google/и т.п. → [первая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59251008/4827341)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это есть и при стандартном билдинге, но он успешно собирается